# JSON.stringify not stringifying the whole object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, stringify

`JSON.stringify(this.workout)`is not stringifying the whole object. `workout`is an object from the class `Workout` which looks like this:

```
export class Workout {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    exercises: Exercise[];
    routine: Routine;
}
```

Exercise and Routine is another Class with also nested arrays.

The problem is `JSON.stringify(this.workout)` return only `{"name":"Day 1"}`. Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: How this particular instance of `Workout` looks like? This one `this.workout` I guess if you are not setting all the properties with some values - JSON.stringify ignores  undefined stuff.

Comment: Just like what John said, try checking what's inside your workout instance particularly your this.workout. It might be that only "name": "Day 1" is in there.

Comment: @john No, `JSON.stringify()` does not ignore `null`.  It *does* ignore `undefined`.

Comment: @Brad I updated my comment because you are absolutely right. I've checked how it works )

Answer (score 2):

For any classes you wish to serialize, you may have to define your to `toJSON()` method to ensure the data is serialized.  Otherwise, only the regular enumerable properties are going to end up in the output.

You'll probably need this on `Exercise` and `Routine` as well as `Workout`.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this example with plain JS, it works as expected, so you should review your code and make sure all the objects are properly initialised.

Alternatively, you can also implement a custom `toJSON` method in any of those classes to define how you want to serialise them (check the example in `class` `Routine`):

```js
class Exercises {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [1, 2, 3];
  }
}

class Routine {
  constructor() {
    this.property = 'DATA';
  }
  
  toJSON() {
    return `ROUTINE = ${ this.property }`;
  }
}

class Workout {
  constructor() {
    this.id = 1;
    this.name = 'Foo';
    this.exercises = new Exercises();
    this.routine = new Routine();
  }
}

const workout = new Workout();

console.log(JSON.stringify(workout, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```